# Is there any way that i can get the authors' keywords from Web Of Science database

Tags: python, data-extraction, bibliography, journal

I need the authors' keywords from Web of Science (WOS) database. This data is saved in WOS, however the search results don't contain keywords but other meta-data, which i also require but i am especially interested in keywords for these documents.

I require around one million articles worth of data. So downloading each paper manually and writing its keywords or using ANN algorithm to write it for me is out of question. I used Master Journals List, and Journal Citation Report for my search queries.

A few sample queries : 
http://wcs.webofknowledge.com/RA/analyze.do?product=WOS&SID=F5k8t6JGuXbofxtseZS&field=TASCA_JCRCategories_JCRCategories_en&yearSort=false

http://apps.webofknowledge.com/CitationReport.do?product=WOS&search_mode=CitationReport&SID=F5k8t6JGuXbofxtseZS&page=1&cr_pqid=3&viewType=summary

Is there a python script, or any other software or some paid version of WOS that i can use to get the keywords for a large list of articles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only place that this data can be exported is on the Results page using the "Export Option" and "Other File Formats" to export the "Full Records".
[image]

I just recieved this answer from technical support at clarivate analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Niot quite what you need, but if you export the records as .bib or .txt you can parse them with the [refsplitr](https://github.com/ropensci/refsplitr) package for R